# Sending JSON string to ASP.NET Core MVC Controller

Tags: json, asp.net-core, controller, transfer

I know how to send simple objects from JavaScript to an ASP.NET Core Controller. But what I'm suppose to do when I have **complex** a JSON string?

For example I'm using Factory lib. in JavaScript, so when I'm serializing my current Canvas data I'm getting JSON string like this:
[image]

The question is : should I create this complex model in my ASP.NET Core app or is there any other way to get this JSON string in my Controller?

Can I consume a simple json string in my Controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to your needs actually.

If you do need a model which provides some methods to process the data, then creating a model could be a good idea.

If you just need to deserialize the JSON string and extract values, you could write your controller like

```
public ActionResult xxx ([FromBody]dynamic postData)
```

It will receive the request body as string now.

Be sure to set content-type as application/json in your javascript code

[image]

Comment: Thx for the reply, I'll try it. If I have an Index method in Home controller, should I write ajax function just like this?
$.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(canvas),
            async: false
        });

Comment: you can check the api in jquery here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, and it should be contentType instead of dataType and charset. You could skip the JSON.stringify as well I guess

Comment: ep, this works. Thanks a lot for your answer instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer looks to use a dynamic object to handle the JSON string.

An alternative approach would be to capture the JSON string into a string.

```
public IActionResult xxx(string id, [FromBody] string jsonString)
```

And then de-serialize it.

```
MyData myData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyData>(jsonString);
```